# Using @JmsListener with multiple payload types for the same destination?

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I can write instances of multiple types to a given destination, e.g.:

```
JmsTemplate template = ...
Alpha alpha = new Alpha(...);
Beta beta = new Beta(...);

template.convertAndSend("my-destination", alpha);
template.convertAndSend("my-destination", beta);
```

I thought I'd then be able to provide multiple `@JmsListener` annotated methods to receive the different message payloads - like so:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "my-destination")
public void receiveAlpha(Alpha alpha) { ... }

@JmsListener(destination = "my-destination")
public void receiveBeta(Beta beta) { ... }
```

But if I try this I get exceptions in `PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument` as it can't distinguish that `Beta` values should be sent to one method and `Alpha` values to another.

How should I be handling this? As I encode the payload type as a message property I can specify a selector to get things to work like so:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "my-destination", selector = "_type = 'Alpha'")
public void receiveAlpha(Alpha alpha) { ... }

@JmsListener(destination = "my-destination", selector = "_type = 'Beta'")
public void receiveBeta(Beta beta) { ... }
```

But as Spring is doing all kinds of cleverness behind the scenes I'm surprised I have to help it out explicitly like this.

Is there a more implicit / better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could set the JmsTemplate's message converter to set the message's Java type into the message's "type" property, and then in the JmsListener, configure the selector for receiving only the desired message type.

Below is an example in Kotlin, and Java should be the same

The default message convert, annotates the message type into "type" property:

```
@Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
fun jacksonJmsMessageConverter(): MessageConverter {
    val converter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()

    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT)
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("type")
    return converter
}
```

With the annotating message converter, JMS listener could specify message type in selector:

```
// Uses default JmsListenerContainerFactory
@JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory", selector="type='com.garnetsoft.sf.service.queue.CopyFolderJob'")
fun receiveMessage(job: CopyFolderJob) {
    println("Received copy job <$job>")
}

@JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory", selector="type='com.garnetsoft.sf.service.queue.CutFolderJob'")
fun receiveMessage(job: CutFolderJob) {
    println("Received cut job <$job>")
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`JmsListener` doesn't support method routing - each annotated method gets its own listener container.

The only other alternative is to use `...(Object object)` and downcast yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set selector property in message postprocessor. Use same property as selector in consumer method. Check this [JMSListener selector not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453364/jmslistener-selector-not-working)

To send to queue:

```
    template.convertAndSend("my-destination", alpha, m -> {
        m.setStringProperty("classType", "alpha");
        return m;
    });
```

To take message from queue:

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "my-destination", selector = "classType = 'alpha'")<br/>
    public void receiveAlpha(Alpha alpha) { ... }
```